# Rear wheel not centered

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, axle

So i just noticed that my rear wheel is not centered. I think it has been like that since i sent my bike for a service 6 months ago. The wheel is brand new[image]

I also noticed a thing which looks like a spacer at the other side of the wheel
[image]

[image]

What if i remove that spacer thingy? Will it be centered or i will have new problems with shifting etc?

Comment: “Not centered” is a bit of an understatement! But sideways-positioning of the hub is probably not the issue, rather it seems the wheel isn't sitting _straight_. Would need some more angles to really know what's going on.

Comment: Did you just disconnect the rear brake or wasn't it connected at all?

Comment: @Carel i disconnected it

Comment: @leftaroundabout what about that spacer thing? Other bikes i've seen don't have this

Comment: Can you verify the axle is properly seated in the dropouts?

Comment: Either the axle is not square in the dropouts, as @whatsisname suggests, or the axle is cracked.

Comment: @AdamRice I replaced the axle about 3 months ago and i have been riding the bike only on road

Comment: I once serviced my hub and unknowingly exchanged the left and right cones, washers and  locknuts (i.e. all the little parts mounted on the ends of the axle), because I thought they were the same. But they were not, and what happened looked very much like your problem, so it may be something similar. Maybe your bike shop made the same mistake I did. When I exchanged the left and right side parts again, the problem was solved.

Comment: It's strange that there's no derailer hanger visible in the second picture.

Comment: @DanielRHicks i removed it because i destroyed it hehe....

Comment: @Mick so you're saying that i should swap the stuff from one side to another?

Comment: Maybe swap the cone nuts and any attached washers or spacers (sometimes the cone nut is part of an assembly of parts. This assembly is what I refer to by "attached washers..."

Comment: The left side stuff (what we can see outside of the cone nut) is normal looking, left sided stuff, albeit that lock nut is quite thick.  Transferring everything over is probably not the way to go.

Comment: Was the derailler damaged in the last 6 months (i.e. after the service)?
Same thing that happened to destroy your derailleur may have bended your chain stays, too. Therefore the frame is bended, while the wheel is straight...

Comment: @EarlGrey No. I destroyed the derailleur 3 weeks ago. I was crusing slowly on a flat road. The chain got caught and twisted it. I think that happened because i accidentally banged the derailleur on the pavement a few days ago